# Copy active cell to last free cell in column A of another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy the active cell to the last free cell in column A of another sheet called "comments".

I tried this code:

```
Sub Macro3()

    'Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl y
    Dim LastRowMaster As Long

    'Take the cell I'm in
    ActiveCell.Select

    'Copy it
    Selection.Copy

    'Go to the sheet I want to paste into
    Sheets("comments").Select

    'Find the last row in my sheet "comments" and +1
    LastRowMaster = Worksheets("comments").Cells(Worksheets("comments").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    'Choose the last free cell in column A
    Range("A:").Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("comments").Cells(LastRowMaster, "A")

    'Copy my paste
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

I get an error

> "Method 'range' of object_global failed

in this line:

```
Range("A:").Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("comments").Cells(LastRowMaster, "A")
```

Answer (score 1):

First, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) and you can speed up and shorten your code.

I think this does what you want (`A:` is not a valid range reference), but I would not advise you to base code on the `activecell`.

```
Sub Macro3()

Dim LastRowMaster As Long

With Worksheets("comments")                                     'avoid repeating this on every line
    LastRowMaster = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ActiveCell.Copy Destination:=.Cells(LastRowMaster, "A")     'copy and paste on the same line
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi SJR,

Thanks for the response.

It seems to be that kind of code I’m looking for. Thanks!

But I forgot that the values I try to copy is from a formula. So, I get an error. Can I do something, so I only copy the values? And not the formula?

Something like:
.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats)

Is that possible?

Thanks again for taking time to help me.

Comment: You can use `.Cells(LastRowMaster, "A").value=activecell.value` to just copy the value, or the approach you suggest (the pastespecial bit needs to be on a separate line).

Answer (score 0):

So the code will be like this?

```
Sub Macro3()

Dim LastRowMaster As Long 
    With Worksheets("comments")
    LastRowMaster = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ActiveCell.Copy Destination:=.Cells(LastRowMaster, "A").Value = ActiveCell.Value  
End With

End Sub
```

It comes up with an error. I properly just missed up a dot/ blank space or something. 
Aaargh, I can’t see the problem.

> Copy method of Range class failed

Comment: Try `.Cells(LastRowMaster, "A").Value = ActiveCell.Value` without `ActiveCell.Copy Destination:=`

Answer (score 0):

This should copy your activecell onto the "comments"sheet in the next empty cell in column A:

```
Sub Macro3()

Dim LastRowMaster As Long 

    With Worksheets("comments")
       LastRowMaster = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
       .Cells(LastRowMaster, "A").Value = ActiveCell.Value  
    End With

End Sub
```